Is there a way to change installation directory of brew cask applications?
I don't have write access to the system wide application folder on my MacBook, so I want to be able to install cask packages to my user application folder. Is this possible with homebrew?

You can override a Homebrew app install location with --appdir:
% brew help install
...
      --appdir                     Target location for Applications (default:
                                   /Applications).

% brew install --cask --appdir ~/Applications app

